# Подключение файлов php

Tags: php, include, require

Ребят, привет. Возник вопрос. Хочу подключить хэдер на страницу, но при этом интерпретатор выдает ошибку о том, что файл не существует. 
[image: Скрин ошибки]

[image: Скрин нахождения файла]

```
<?php require_once ('../../site_parts/header.php'); ?>
```

Подскажите, в чем ошибка состоит?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка не в этой строчке, а во второй строчке файла *header.php*. В этой строчке вы, по всей видимости, подключаете *function/main_menu.php*. И вот этот файл и не находит. По видимому, у него другой адрес по отношению к запускаемому вами. Для сохранения относительных путей вне зависимости от запускаемого файла используйте волшебную константу `__DIR__`.

Пример:

```
<?php 

include __DIR__ . '/../../site_parts/function/main_menu.php';
include __DIR__ . '/../../site_parts/header.php';
```